# Spark2.2.1 incompatible Jackson version 2.8.8

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark

My configuration is:

- Scala 2.11 (plugin Scala IDE)
- Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
- Windows 7 64bit

I want run this simple scala code (Esempio.scala):

```
package it.scala

// importo packages di Spark
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf


object Wordcount {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val inputs: Array[String] = new Array[String](2)
        inputs(0) = "C:\\Users\\FobiDell\\Desktop\\input"
        inputs(1) = "C:\\Users\\FobiDell\\Desktop\\output"

        // oggetto SparkConf per settare i parametri sulla propria applicazione 
        // da fornire poi al cluster manager scelto (Yarn, Mesos o Standalone).
        val conf = new SparkConf()
        conf.setAppName("Smartphone Addiction")
        conf.setMaster("local")

        // oggetto SparkContext per connessione al cluster manager scelto
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

        //Read file and create RDD
        val rawData = sc.textFile(inputs(0))

        //convert the lines into words using flatMap operation
        val words = rawData.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))

        //count the individual words using map and reduceByKey operation
        val wordCount = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

        //Save the result
        wordCount.saveAsTextFile(inputs(1))

       //stop the spark context
       sc.stop

   }

}
```

So, if I use the Spark-shell everything is ok otherwise, from Eclipse IDE, if I select the file (Esempio.scala) and run it via Run->Run as->Scala application, I obtain this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:830)
    at it.scala.Wordcount$.main(Esempio.scala:47)
    at it.scala.Wordcount.main(Esempio.scala)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.8.8
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:745)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
    ... 4 more
```

My pom.xml file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>it.hgfhgf.xhgfghf</groupId>
  <artifactId>progetto</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>progetto</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Neo4j JDBC DRIVER -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Scala -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.11</version>
    </dependency> 

    <!-- Spark -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>


</project>
```

I noticed that the .jar files that are into spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars directory are:

- jackson-core-2.6.5.jar
- jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar
- jackson-module-paranamer-2.6.5.jar
- jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.6.5.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar

Can anyone explain to me in simple terms what this exception is and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 43):

Spark 2.x contains the `jackson 2.6.5`  and `neo4j-jdbc-driver` uses `jackson 2.8.8` version, here the dependency conflict between two different version of jackson library.
That's why you are getting this `Incompatible Jackson version: 2.8.8` error.

Try to override the dependency version for these[below] modules inside your `pom.xml` and see if works,

1. jackson-core
2. jackson-databind
3. jackson-module-scala_2.x

or try adding below dependency into your pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: The last bit (adding an explicit `jackson-module-scala` dependency is the best option because it lets you use an arbitrary version of Jackson and Scala together, instead of being at the mercy of whatever Jackson version a specific version of Scala defaults to.

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if this helps anyone whos had the problem with an sbt project thats using scala 2.12. Putting in **jackson-module-scala_2.11** doesn't quite work. There a single version of jackson-module-scala 2.6.7 that has a scala 2.12 build

Following line in build.sbt worked

```
dependencyOverrides ++= {
  Seq(
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.6.7.1",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.7",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.6.7"
  )
}
```

This fixed the problem for spark 2.4.5

Comment: You saved me a ton of time ! Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Scala version 2.1.1 works with Jackson 2.6.5.  Use the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did run into the same version conflict of Jackson. In addition to override jackson-core, jackson-databind, jackson-module-scala_2.x, I also defined jackson-annotations in my pom.xml, which solved the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**

This exception occurs when there is a dependency conflict between two different versions of the Jackson library.

To resolve conflicts maven proceeds as follows:

1. It uses a a nearest-wins strategy.
2. If dependencies are on the same level, in that case maven would resolve the conflict by simply using the one, which has a higher position in pom.

This can lead to picking to wrong Jackson version.

**Solution:**

To detect the conflict, you can use in intelliJ the plugin [Maven Helper](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper). It will allow you to exclude conflictuel dependencies using the `<exclusions>` element in the  element by which the problematic jar is included.

**Note**:
This error can also happen when trying to launch a spark Job on cluster mode. In this case, you have to specify explicitally the jar using the **spark.driver.extraClassPath** and **spark.executor.extraClassPath** configurations with the **spark-submit** command.

```
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting error Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.9-3

I added
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.14.0" in build.sbt
.build project(Build => Rebuild project)
.Invalidate and restart(file=>Invalidate cache)
it's worked for me

Comment: I was getting error:  Incompatible Jackson version: 2.12.7-1  and this 2.14.0 version of jackson-module-scala worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is the combination that worked for me .

 aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
 hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar
 joda-time-2.9.6.jar
 hadoop-client-2.7.3-sources.jar
 hadoop-client-2.7.3.jar
 hadoop-client-2.6.0-javadoc.jar
 hadoop-client-2.6.0.jar
 jets3t-0.9.4.jar
 jackson-core-2.10.0.jar
 jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar
 jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.8.5.jar
 jackson-annotations-2.8.7.jar
```